# CSS: Using flexbox for simplifying HTML structure

Tags: html, css, flexbox

For example i have this layout. It includes:

- An image on left part. This image will be center vertically
- Some text on right part display line by line.

[image]

I can do as structure html like this and using some layout such as Flexbox, div positioning ...

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <image class="avatar"></image>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="name">JameyJohnson</div>
    <div class="quote">I had little patience to begin with</div>
    <div class="date">6/10/2017</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to apply Flexbox and also simply this html (no wrapper against the text part)

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <image class="avatar"></image>
  <div class="name">JameyJohnson</div>
  <div class="quote">I had little patience to begin with</div>
  <div class="date">6/10/2017</div>
</div>
```

Can I use Flexbox for above html structure. If yes, please tell me how.

Comment: For that you will need flex column, and with that a fixed height on the `wrapper`, which will limit the responsiveness of the text (when text might wrap, the `wrapper` won't). Still wan't that ?

Comment: In my case, height of wrapper is constant. (ie: always 70px). I don't think there is a case height will be less than that. (ie: user make height of browser too small)

Comment: Posted an answer with 2 samples.

Comment: Let me know if my answer were helpful and can be upvoted and/or accepted? ... and if not, is there something I can adjust, add or explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you will need flex column, and with that a fixed height on the `wrapper`, which will limit the responsiveness of the text (when text might wrap, the `wrapper` won't resize).

*Note, for custom elements to work properly, use `my-` in front of its type name.*

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;          /*  made it inline so it collapse to content width  */
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
}
my-image.avatar {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/30/f00) no-repeat left center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
}

/* sample with img */
.avatar {
  width: 30px;
  order: -1;                    /*  move before pseudo  */
}
.wrapper.nr2::before {          /*  a delimiter that break into a column of its own  */
  content: '';
  height: 70px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <my-image class="avatar"></my-image>
  <div class="name">JameyJohnson</div>
  <div class="quote">I had little patience to begin with</div>
  <div class="date">6/10/2017</div>
</div>

<div></div>

<div class="wrapper nr2">
  <img class="avatar" src="http://placehold.it/30/f00">
  <div class="name">JameyJohnson</div>
  <div class="quote">I had little patience to begin with</div>
  <div class="date">6/10/2017</div>
</div>
```

---

Another option is to use `background-image` on the `wrapper`, and give it a left padding (all this done w/o Flexbox :).

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  padding-left: 50px;
}
.avatar {
  background: url(http://placehold.it/30/f00) no-repeat left center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper avatar">
  <div class="name">JameyJohnson</div>
  <div class="quote">I had little patience to begin with</div>
  <div class="date">6/10/2017</div>
</div>
```

---

*Updated*

In case someone needs to set the image source in the markup, that can also be done when using `background-image`, like this, inline

Stack snippet

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;          /*  made it inline so it collapse to content width  */
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 70px;
}
my-image.avatar {
  background-position: left center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <my-image class="avatar" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/30/f00);"></my-image>
  <div class="name">JameyJohnson</div>
  <div class="quote">I had little patience to begin with</div>
  <div class="date">6/10/2017</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks so much for your answer :D it helps me. The only thing I don't want is set background image inside CSS. Because this background image is dynamic. But anyway by using code, I can set it by myself, but it is not pretty. (I'm using React). So I'm just waiting are there any solutions else :D

Comment: @TrầnKimDự Thanks ... and do note that I use an `img` in the 1st Stack snippets 2nd sample, not `background-image`. And you know that you can set a `background-image` in the markup as well, yes?

Comment: @TrầnKimDự Good...and I also added a 3rd snippet explaining/showing that :)